# reroute URL to site keeping domain name

Tags: domain-name

How do i have ThisDomain.com goto sub.SomeFreeSite.com and have the url look like ThisDomain.com?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of 3 ways off the top of my head:

1. get SomeFreeSite.com to set up sub with alias of ThisDomain.com and point DNS at them. Requires they support that kind of setup; many free sites support that for extra charge.
2. set up server for ThisDomain.com and set up proxy on it (one or two lines to do with apache). you end up passing all the bandwidth and might as well host it yourself
3. set up server for ThisDomain.com and have a single page with an iframe.  lots of UI issues, but sorta works